# Basic Programming regarding some if statements

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to set up some algorithms for a programmer.

Let me give you an example and tell me how one can program it:

- If `a = 1 ;` give statement `" 123  "`
- if `b = 1 ;` give statement `" 234 "`
- If `c = 1 ;` give statement `" 345 "`
- If `a, b, c /= 1`, do nothing.
- If `a and b  = 1 ;` give statement `" 123 + 234 "`

How do I set up the algorithm so that, when two factors are true, for example
in the case above when both `a` and `b` are `1`, only `" 123 + 234"` is shown and will not
give me : `123, 234, 123 + 234`.

*Does this make sense?*

Please do not give me your answer in code, but just simple layman's term so I can understand it.

Comment: Start with the most specific check.

Comment: What do you mean by "give statement"?  Do you want to execute the statement on that line number, or print the value, or something else?  Also, what sort of BASIC are you using?  Not all implementations do all the same things.

Comment: Hey! consider accepting one of the answers, for completeness. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just after the `if ... else if .... else if ...` construct.

Also, to keep the code clean, start with the most specific cases:

If a and b = 1 ; give statement " 123 + 234 "

*ELSE* if a = 1 ; give statement " 123 "

*ELSE* if b = 1 ; give statement " 234 "

*ELSE* If c = 1 ; give statement " 345 "

*ELSE* If a, b, c /= 1, do nothing.

(Last line you can obviously skip!)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is basic [logical connectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective). Depending on what programming language you'll use, there should be plenty of tutorials and those kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

```
if a = 1 AND b = 1; give statement "123 + 234";
else if a = 1 ; give statement " 123 ";
else if b = 1 ; give statement " 234 ";
else if c = 1 ; give statement " 345 ";
```

What you need to do is get the most explicit cases out of the way first.

Answer (score 1):

Zero is correct in that the language is going to determine what you can do. Some basic concepts for what you are asking that I would look into if I were you would be switch, case, nested if (iif). Those seem to be available in some form in most languages.

Answer (score 1):

Set d=0

If a = 1 ; set d=1
         ; give statement " 123 "

if b = 1 ; if d=1; give statement "+"
         ; give statement " 234 "

If c = 1 ; if d=1; give statement "+"
         ; give statement " 345 "

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding it a little difficult to understand what you are asking but I'll take a stab at it. I think what you are wanting to know is how to make a variable equal to "" to true if two or more statements are themselves true let that variable be equal to 123 + 234.

So in PHP:

```
if ($a = 1 && $b = 1) {
   echo "123 + 234";
   // or do whatever else it is you want. 
}
```

The key in your case is '`&&`'. Both conditions must be met.

Comment: Both the question title and the tag say `Basic`. Why are you posting PHP code as an answer? (And stressing the `&&` operator when Basic doesn't use it for `and`?)

Comment: ops.. My mistake. I did not see the tag and I took "basic" out of context.

Comment: You may want to delete it before it starts getting downvoted, or at least edit it to remove the PHP code. :)

Comment: By "Basic" the OP means "simple"